# Showing $\mathbb{Q}\cong \mathbb{Q}\otimes_\mathbb{Z}\mathbb{Q}$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, tensor-products

I want to prove the following, $$\mathbb{Q}\cong \mathbb{Q}\otimes_\mathbb{Z}\mathbb{Q}.$$

I know that the map $f:\mathbb{Q}\rightarrow \mathbb{Q}\otimes_\mathbb{Z}\mathbb{Q}$ defined by $f(q)=q\otimes 1$ is a homomorphism so I just need to show that it is bijective. It is obviously onto, but for one to one I take $\frac{n}{d}$ from the kernel of $f$. So $0=f(n/d) = n/d\otimes 1$, but I don't know how this implies $n/d=0$. Any suggestions?

Comment: Please ignore that edit, I misread your statement. As to your question, it boils down to the question what the zero element in $\mathbb{Q} \otimes_\mathbb{Z} \mathbb{Q}$ is

Comment: Yes, the tensor product confuses me and I'm not sure how to write the 0 element. My thought is $0_S\otimes_R 0_T$ in $S\otimes_R T$, where $0_S$ and $0_T$ are the respective zeros of the modules $S$ and $T$. Which would imply $0_S\otimes_R 0_T = 0_Rs\otimes_R 0_Rt$ for any $s\in S$ and $t\in T$ if I'm not mistaken

Comment: Though that is certainly the zero element, it's not its most general form. Namely, you should think of it rather as $0_S \otimes t$ for arbitrary $t \in T$ or equivalently as $s \otimes 0_T$ for arbitrary $s \in S$. As the answer by Hurkyl shows, you should think of the tensor product literally as the $\mathbb{Z}$-module $\mathbb{Q}^2$ MODULO the equivalence relation by which you only care about their product (which is now a single rational number). I guess that's the moral of why the above is an isomorphism.

Comment: or that $Q$ is a field so no zero divisors so $a\otimes1=0 \implies a=0$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is often the case that it is more convenient to prove something is an isomorphism *directly* by writing down its inverse, rather than by the indirect route of proving it is bijective.

This case is no different: the evident inverse is the function

$$ g : \mathbb{Q} \otimes_{\mathbb{Z}} \mathbb{Q} : x \otimes y \mapsto xy $$

so all you need to do is show that $g$ is well defined, and that $f \circ g$ and $g \circ f$ are the identity maps.