# Proof that $\Bbb Q\cong \Bbb Q\otimes_{\Bbb Z}\Bbb Q$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, tensor-products

I am trying to prove that $\Bbb Q\otimes_{\Bbb Z}\Bbb Q\cong\Bbb Q$.  I know that $\frac a b \otimes \frac c d = 1\otimes \frac{ac}{bd}$ and therefore it makes sense to define the map $\varphi:\Bbb Q\to \Bbb Q\otimes_{\Bbb Z}\Bbb Q$ by
$$\varphi(q) = 1\otimes q$$
and we need to confirm that this is an isomorphism.

The part I struggle with here is injectivity, since if we assume $1\otimes q=1\otimes r$ then we need to prove $q=r$.  But from the definition of the tensor product we only know that if $H\subseteq \Bbb Q\times \Bbb Q$ is generated by familiar relations, such that $\Bbb Q\otimes_{\Bbb Z}\Bbb Q = \Bbb Q\times\Bbb Q/H$ then we have that there is some $(s,t)\in H$ such that $(1,q)=(1,r)+(s,t)$, so $(0,q-r)=(s,t)$ and therefore $s=0$ and $q-r=t$.  This implies $(0,q-r)\in H$, but from here, I'm not sure what to do with it.

I could argue that there is some $\Bbb Z$-linear combination of the generators of $H$ which equals $(0,q-r)$, but I don't see any way to make use of this fact.  Since I don't know much else about the tensor product, then I'm somewhat out of ideas at this point.

---

I have seen this post: [Showing $\mathbb{Q}\cong \mathbb{Q}\otimes_\mathbb{Z}\mathbb{Q}$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2211151/showing-mathbbq-cong-mathbbq-otimes-mathbbz-mathbbq?rq=1)

and tried to prove that this inverse map is well-defined, and it seems to me that this runs into exactly the same problem.

Comment: Hint: To prove well-definedness of the inverse map, use the universal property of tensor products.

Comment: There is absolutely no problem in the answer of the duplicate you linked to. Follow @PaceNielsen 's hint above. Btw, in case you are not so sure of your initial claim (useless at this stage) "I know that $\frac a b \otimes \frac c d = 1\otimes \frac{ac}{bd}$" : https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2542075

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$V=\Bbb Q\otimes_{\Bbb Z}\Bbb Q$ is an extension of scalars from $\Bbb{Z}$ to $\Bbb{Q}$ with multiplication defined on the left coordinate $a(u\otimes v) = (au)\otimes v$ for $a\in \Bbb{Q}, u\otimes v\in V$.  You already know however that $(au)\otimes v = u\otimes (av)$.  The map you defined
$$\varphi(q) = 1\otimes q$$
is surjective, and it is $\Bbb{Q}$-linear because
$$\varphi(aq) = 1\otimes (aq) = a\otimes q = a(1\otimes q) = a\varphi(q)$$
So $\varphi$ is a surjective $\Bbb{Q}$-linear map from a $1$-dimensional vector space over $\Bbb{Q}$ to a vector space over $\Bbb{Q}$.  It follows that either $V=0$ or $V=\Bbb{Q}$.  So it's enough to prove for example that $1\otimes 1 \ne 0$ in $V$ and for that you can define any explicit binlinear map $\Bbb{Q} \times \Bbb{Q}\to M$ for some vector space $M$ over $\Bbb{Q}$ such that $(1,1)$ does not map to zero.

Comment: Or simply: define $(x,y)\mapsto xy,$ as hinted above, which was essentially [the answer to the duplicate](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2211165/386889).

Comment: @AnneBauval: I was trying to play along with doing it in this direction, but ultimately there is no avoiding defining bilinear forms on $\Bbb{Q} \times \Bbb{Q}$ to show that $V\ne 0$ and also to show that $V$ has no torsion elements which is needed for the identity $(au)\otimes v = u\otimes (av)$ with $a\in \Bbb{Q}$.

Comment: These lemmas (about $V\ne0$ and torsion) are useless, the direct proof of the duplicate is much shorter and  imo more natural. As for $(au)\otimes v = u\otimes (av),$ see the link in my 1st comment above.https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2542080/386889